# How do I print out the items selected rather reference code?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
```

`class OrderModel: NSObject {
    var menuItem = "None"
    var modifier = "None"
}`

this is my code which returns

`Optional("Confirm")
[<ParseStarterProject_Swift.OrderModel: 0x7f92da5404c0>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.OrderModel: 0x7f92da72d7e0>`

as a print option I'm running on a confirm order button.

I have another method called

```
import UIKit
```

`class OrderList :NSObject{
    var list:[OrderModel] = []
    func addList(model:OrderModel){
        list = list + [model]
    }
}`

how do print out my order items?

this is my print function 
`print(self.orderList.list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically u are trying to print out the reference directory of the object but not the value inside it, Try this:

```
for order:OrderModel in self.orderList.list {
   print(order.menuItem)
   print(order.modifier)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate . tough me something too. that just did it :)